# Merging .vec files

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, vector

Hi I am using this code:

```
import sys
import glob
import struct
import argparse
import traceback


def exception_response(e):
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', dest='vec_directory')
    parser.add_argument('-o', dest='output_filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return (args.vec_directory, args.output_filename)

def merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_vec_file):
    """
    Iterates throught the .vec files in a directory and combines them.
    (1) Iterates through files getting a count of the total images in the .vec files
    (2) checks that the image sizes in all files are the same
    The format of a .vec file is:
    4 bytes denoting number of total images (int)
    4 bytes denoting size of images (int)
    2 bytes denoting min value (short)
    2 bytes denoting max value (short)
    ex:     6400 0000 4605 0000 0000 0000
        hex     6400 0000   4605 0000       0000        0000
                # images    size of h * w       min     max
        dec         100         1350            0       0
    :type vec_directory: string
    :param vec_directory: Name of the directory containing .vec files to be combined.
                Do not end with slash. Ex: '/Users/username/Documents/vec_files'
    :type output_vec_file: string
    :param output_vec_file: Name of aggregate .vec file for output.
        Ex: '/Users/username/Documents/aggregate_vec_file.vec'
    """

    # Check that the .vec directory does not end in '/' and if it does, remove it.
    if vec_directory.endswith('/'):
        vec_directory = vec_directory[:-1]
    # Get .vec files
    files = glob.glob('{0}/*.vec'.format(vec_directory))

    # Check to make sure there are .vec files in the directory
    if len(files) <= 0:
        print('Vec files to be mereged could not be found from directory: {0}'.format(vec_directory))
        sys.exit(1)
    # Check to make sure there are more than one .vec files
    if len(files) == 1:
        print('Only 1 vec file was found in directory: {0}. Cannot merge a single file.'.format(vec_directory))
        sys.exit(1)


    # Get the value for the first image size
    prev_image_size = 0
    try:
        with open(files[0], 'rb') as vecfile:
            content = b''.join((line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
            val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
            prev_image_size = val[1]
    except IOError as e:
        print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
        exception_response(e)


    # Get the total number of images
    total_num_images = 0
    for f in files:
        try:
            with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:
                content = b''.join((line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
                val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
                num_images = val[0]
                image_size = val[1]
                if image_size != prev_image_size:
                    err_msg = """The image sizes in the .vec files differ. These values must be the same. \n The image size of file {0}: {1}\n
                        The image size of previous files: {0}""".format(f, image_size, prev_image_size)
                    sys.exit(err_msg)

                total_num_images += num_images
        except IOError as e:
            print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
            exception_response(e)


    # Iterate through the .vec files, writing their data (not the header) to the output file
    # '<iihh' means 'little endian, int, int, short, short'
    header = struct.pack('<iihh', total_num_images, image_size, 0, 0)
    try:
        with open(output_vec_file, 'wb') as outputfile:
            outputfile.write(header)

            for f in files:
                with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:
                    content = b''.join((line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
                    outputfile.write(bytearray(content[12:]))
    except Exception as e:
        exception_response(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vec_directory, output_filename = get_args()
    if not vec_directory:
        sys.exit('mergvec requires a directory of vec files. Call mergevec.py with -v /your_vec_directory')
    if not output_filename:
        sys.exit('mergevec requires an output filename. Call mergevec.py with -o your_output_filename')

merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_filename)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
 File "mergevec.py", line 95, in merge_vec_files
    with open(output_vec_file, 'wb') as outputfile:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output_vec_file'
```

My goal is to merge the vector files together to create one vector file as part of a haar cascade in opencv. I just updated this post, and there is a lot of code so I am currently using this as filler text, but yeah any help that you can give me is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The syntax error is for forgetting to put a : at the end of def merge_vec_files

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I did not catch that. Thank you. Now, I am getting this error, unfortunately: File "Merge_Vecs.py", line 22

                                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined the function merge_vec_files. I'm not an expert at merging these kinds of files. I'm just trying to help out with a couple of the syntax errors

Comment: I tried using the terminal to give it the directory of the vector files and then the desired output folder, do you know of another way I could do that?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with OpenCV, you just do not have _permission_ to write to a file (or to create one). To solve this, refer to the documentation of your OS.

Comment: @ForceBru what do you mean?

Comment: @ChrisB, this error means that your OS (namely, your user's privileges) is configured in such a way that said user doesn't have permission to write or create files. To solve this, you need to reconfigure the settings of your OS or the concrete directory you're trying to write to in order to allow that user to do this. This doesn't have anything to do with OpenCV, though.